# Can't run the file "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: c++, clion, c++-winrt

[image]

I'm new to cpp and just installed clion
I started a new project with the default "hello world!" text program of clion
but when I hit run button it doesn't show anything and sends a weird number for exit code.

Comment: That means "Access Violation" which means your program attempted to access memory it does not own.

Comment: Seeing your picture you most likely have [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) which means you have some other version of the dlls of your compiler's runtime in your `PATH` environment variable and windows is loading the other incompatible version instead of the one that matches your compiler. This could be caused by another version of MinGW installed or other software that was built using MinGW.

Comment: Your helloworld code seems impecable, but always better copy-paste your code directly (without line numbers), so it can be replicable by others. Sometimes typing from images could add extra typos or even things that look good on images could have very subtle typos hard to detect (periods, colons, semicolons, brackets, etc). Better send raw code.

Comment: Related to my previous comment search your system for these files: `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libstdc++6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll`

Comment: thanks guys, I added my mingw path to toolchain in clion setting and it worked

Comment: That likely caused it to insert the compiler's folder first in the `PATH` environment variable. The order of the `PATH` is very important because the OS searches in order and stops searching after it finds a match to the dll name.